# Deferred binding not working after compilation

Tags: gwt

I have a weird problem with deferred binding. I have defined the following module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Defines the usercategory property and its provider function. -->
<module>

    <define-property name="usercategory" values="c00,c01,c02" />
    <collapse-property name="usercategory" values="*" />

    <property-provider name="usercategory"><![CDATA[
        // Look for the usercategory cookie
        var cs = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
            var name = cs[i].substr(0, cs[i].indexOf("="));
            var value = cs[i].substr(cs[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
            name = name.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
            if (name == "usercategory") {
                return unescape(value);
            }
        }

        return "c00";
    ]]></property-provider>

</module>
```

which sets the property `usercategory` by looking at the value of a cookie named `usercategory`.

I use this property application.gwt.xml to defer binding of some classes, for example:

```
<inherits name="com.example.UserCategory"/>

<replace-with class="com.example.client.ui.menu.MainMenuView01">
  <when-type-is class="com.example.client.ui.menu.MainMenuView"/>
  <when-property-is name="usercategory" value="c01"/>
</replace-with>
```

This works like a charm when I'm in development mode (i.e. when running my app from within Eclipse). However, if I compile the app and deploy it (in Jetty, but I don't this this is the problem), then deferred binding does not seem to work, and the expected classes are not loaded. I've checked and the cookie is set up properly with the correct value `c01`, but class `com.example.client.ui.menu.MainMenuView01` is not loaded.

Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to place debugging statements into the property provider to see what's going on? Like `console.log` to output some values being parsed?

Comment: I've tried that. The message on `console.log` come out as I expect, but the application does not behave as I expect: the `com.example.client.ui.menu.MainMenuView01` is not loaded. However, I've noticed that if I click the reload button of the browser, then everything works fine ... just don't know why. Anyway, I can't ask my user to click reload :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was, and I'm writing it here in case others might be interested.

The module that I defined (see code in my question) defines a property whose value is taken from a cookie, that is generated after the user logs in the application.

Originally I had a [GWT Place](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) for the login, and when the user successfully authenticated the application moved to another Place. In this case when the user enter the application, and the GWT Javascript is downloaded to the browser, the cookie is not set yet (because the user has not performed login yet). Therefore the deferred binding does not work, and the expected classes (like `com.example.client.ui.menu.MainMenuView01`) are not loaded.

I have no idea why this works correctly when run in development mode. Anyway. the solution that I implemented is to move the login phase outside of the GWT application, and when the login is successful, I add the cookie and the redirect the user to the actual GWT application.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities. You are doing something wrong, or there is another bug in GWT compiler. I've tried to implement a case like your and it was working when compiled without any problems. So most likely there can be some error on your side. So what i recommend to do is to compile app with -style PRETTY and see how it was compiled. find function named com_example_client_ui_menu_MainMenuView(), and see if it able to create MainMenuView01, try to debug it and etc. Anyway this kind of stuff should be working without any problems.

Also try to debug your property provider (and use vars $doc and $wnd in property provider instead of window)

Another possible case is that the cookie might be not readable from JS

Comment: I may have done something wrong, but why is this same code working properly when run in development mode?

Comment: Since I don't have your code, I can't say why. There are a lot of possibilities, from GWT.isScript() to difference between the data returned in production and local environment (for example app flow might be different because of some production settings so the GWT.create for soft permutation isn't even called). Some compiler glitch is also possibility (I've encountered few cases when GWT compiler removed some useful code).Try to debug compiled application to see if the problem is really with deferred binding.

Comment: I'm trying to debug. I've noticed that if I click the reload button of the browser, then everything works fine ... just don't know why. Anyway, I can't ask my user to click reload